# i want to know how i get corresponding value of columns to the selective columns value

Tags: labview

I am trying to get those rows from the table which is corresponding to the selective indexes. For example, i have one xls file in which different columns of data. currently my code search the selective two columns and their indexes also, know i want to search those selective rows corresponding elements which is in different rows.
Lets A B C D E F G are columns name in which 1000 of rows of numbers 
like

```
 A B c D E F G
 1 3 4 5 6 3 3
 3 4 5 6 3 2 7 
 .............
 4 7 3 2 5 3 2
```

So Currently my code search two specific columns (lets suppose B and F selective values which is in some range), now i want to search column A value which is present in those selective ranges.

```
B F A
3 4 5
3 5 3
7 7 3
5 4 6
...
```

like this

This is my current code VI

[image]

[image]

Comment: To understand correctly: So far, you filter on column B and F, and now, you want to filter on B, F and A? Is this final, or are you going to filer on B, F, C tomorrow, or even B, F, A, C ?

Comment: I think he's saying that if there is, say, a "3" at index B1 (or at F1) and also a "3" at A1, then return the index of that element. Hard to tell without more information.

Comment: Hi Sweber and Dave. for example, columns A and B values and their selected values indexes both are  searched and stored in Array of Index and LacI & TetR array respectively. Now i want to search those values which is corresponding to these selected values in column C.

Comment: Can we have one concrete example to work with? Just a small set of sample data, what inputs it takes and also the expected outcome?

Comment: i added one picture above see this one. I need data like that, the column C data which is in range of column D and J. For example range is 15 to 16, so Column C data which is in between 15 16 range of columns D and J, we store in separate array.

Comment: for example in column D and J the same element are 16 is found then the correspond element is C column is 253 is stored in new array

Comment: So you combine D & J, get the min/max values and that makes your range. And then you want to return all of the indices in C that fall inside that range. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: yes thats i want

Comment: Hi Dave_st, thanks for replying. but this not that what i want. i need simple logic, there are three columns let suppose (A B and C). if A and B columns values are same then the corresponding value of C columns will store in array.

Comment: A= 1 2 43 45 32 54 3, B = 34 2 43 2 45 23 4 23 4 23 23 34 34 34, C= 34 34 23 54 34 23. Now in column A and B the third index number 43 are same. And in corresponding value in column C are 23 so the 23 value store in array. I hope now its clear

Answer (score 1):

I hope we've finally gotten to the bottom of it. How about this one?

[image]